# Cannot take or print the wstring elements from char triple pointer

Tags: c++, linux, gcc

Could I get some help please on the following code ?

```
int main()
{
    char ***dir= new char**[ 256 ];

    static  char    *sDir[2];
    static  char    sDList[2][256];
    wstring gResourcePath = L"/home/cri";

    for (int i=0; i<2; i++)
    {
        sDir[i] = sDirList[i];
    }


    wstring temp1 = gResourcePath + L"/Font";
    sprintf( sDList[0], "%ls", temp1.c_str()) ;

    wstring temp2 = gResourcePath + L"/CMap";
    sprintf( sDList[1], "%ls", temp2.c_str()) ;


    *dir= sDir;

    for (int i=0; i<2; i++)
    {
        wcout << dir[ i ] << "\n";
    }



    return 0;
}
```

I want to be able to extract the elements from the dir:

```
/home/cri/Dir1

/home/cri/Dir2
```

The output I get is:

```
0x602400

0
```

I am using Eclipse CDT with GCC 4.4 on Linux

Comment: Is there a strong reasoning why you are using pointers here at all? You should be better off using a standard container like `std::vector` and `std::string`.

Comment: I am using a framework having this structure.

Answer (score 0):

```
wcout << *dirListP[i] << "\n";
```

Simply add a `*` in the `wcout`. Without it, you were accessing the address of the char** instead of its value.

Comment: thank you for answer. Adding `*dirListP[i]` will print `/home/cri/Font` but for `i = 1` the program crushes :(

Comment: Well, using pointers is often tricky. So, do you *really* need pointers instead of `std::vector`?

Comment: Yes, I need this because of a framework that I'm using

Comment: @cristian You didn't allocate any memory for the results of `sprintf()`.

Comment: You refer to the `sDirList` ? Sould I do more then specifying `char    *sDirListP[2];` ?